# If whenever $\psi_n\rightharpoonup 0$, $A\psi_n \rightharpoonup 0$ then $A$ is bounded.

Tags: functional-analysis, weak-convergence

This if from a previous Princeton [exam](https://web.math.princeton.edu/%7Ejs129/PDFs/teaching/MAT520_fall_2023/Final.pdf) on functional analysis

> Let $A$ be a linear operator $A: X\rightarrow Y$ between normed vector spaces. If  $\psi_n\rightharpoonup 0$ implies  $A\psi_n \rightharpoonup 0$, then $A$ is bounded.

I tried to argue by contradiction. Boundedness is equivalent to continuity at zero, so suppose by way of contradiction that there exists a sequence $\psi_n \rightarrow0$ and $\varepsilon>0$ such that $\lVert A\psi_n\rVert\geq \varepsilon$.

Because $\psi_n\rightharpoonup 0$ this would imply $A\psi_n \rightharpoonup 0$, in spite of the fact $\lVert A\psi_n\rVert\geq \varepsilon$. I thought this might yield a contradiction, but then I remembered that $e_n\rightharpoonup0$ in $l_2$ in spite of the fact $\lVert e_n \rVert_\infty =1$, so this is definitely not the way to go for a contradiction.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Weakly bounded sets ( in particular weakly convergent sequences are norm bounded).

If $A$ is not bounded we can find unit vectors $x_n$ with $\|Ax_n\|\to \infty$.  Let $y_n=\frac {x_n} {\sqrt {\|Ax_n\|}}$. Then $\|y_n\|\to 0$ so $y_n \to 0$ weakly and so does $(A(y_n))$, making this sequence bounded in the norm. But $\|Ay_n\|=\sqrt {\|Ax_n\|} \to \infty$.

Comment: If $x_n \to x$ weakly then $\{x,x_1,x_2,...\}$ is weakly compact, hence norm bounded. @Kadmos